# were having to make everything up

Tags: progressive-aspect, semi-modals, modality

> When he talks of "enemies of the people", the analogies with Stalinist Russia and other 20th-century regimes are so glaring that you have to keep reminding yourself that the French Revolutionaries **were having to** make everything up as they went along, against a very different background from that of the 20th-century tyrannies. ([Source](http://www.independent.co.uk/arts-entertainment/books/reviews/fatal-purity-robespierre-and-the-french-revolution-by-ruth-scurr-477223.html))

Is the phrase "were having to" a progressive form of "to have", which is the indirect expression of the modal verb "must"? I must admit that I have never come across this form.

Could I write just "Revolutionaries **had** to make everything up" without changing the meaning?

P.S. And what about this swap of aspect:

> "Revolutionaries **had to** make everything up as they **were going** along".

Answer (score 2):

My guess is that the progressive aspect is used due to the presence of one phrase. I will mark it in bold:

> When he talks of "enemies of the people", the analogies with Stalinist Russia and other 20th-century regimes are so glaring that you have to keep reminding yourself that the French Revolutionaries were having to make everything up **as they went along**, against a very different background from that of the 20th-century tyrannies.

The time expression "as they went along" imparts a continuous sense to the clause, and "were having to make everything" dovetails with this continuous sense.

P.S. Per *alephzero*'s comment below, note also this clause:

> When he talks of "enemies of the people", the analogies with Stalinist Russia and other 20th-century regimes are so glaring that **you have to keep reminding yourself** that the French Revolutionaries were having to make everything up as they went along, against a very different background from that of the 20th-century tyrannies.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. And what about this change? "Revolutionaries had to make everything up as they were going along". May be I am wrong but it seems to me that the continuous aspect fits better to the second part of the sentence. Does it make sense?

Comment: @bart-leby - did you mean to say that "**were going along**" is possibly better than "**went along**"?

Comment: I do not dare say better. As a non-native speaker I would like only to know whether my version (with a swapped progressive aspect) is possible.

Comment: @bart-leby - I've added this to your main question, and hopefully a native speaker arrives and tells us, since I'm a non-native too. (0:

Comment: +1 This is exactly right. The author employs the progressive to emphasize that in the 18th century revolution was a *process* in which the revolutionaries kept encountering unprecedented situations. 20th century revolutionaries like Stalin had the experience of the French Revolution to look back on.

Comment: Stylistically I think this stems from "you have to keep reminding yourself" earlier in the sentence. You have to *repeat* the act of reminding yourself, just as the revolutionaries had to *repeat* the act of "making something up" to deal with new situations. To me, it seems to read better if you either omit the progressive form in all *three* verbs:  ".. you have to remind yourself ... they had make everything up ... they went along", or include it in all three: "... you have keep reminding yourself ... they were having to make everything up ... they were going along".

Comment: @alephzero - thank you, I've added a mention of it in my answer!

Comment: Since you are not a native speaker, and also because you do not have anything close to a native speaker's grasp of how English speakers use English, it is really a disservice for the OP for you to be guessing here. I think the least you should do is preface *every* "answer" you write with: I am a non-native speaker and this is only my best guess." But ultimately I think you should refrain from "answering" (= guessing) here and find somewhere that you can answer questions about your native language. And hopefully you won't be guessing when you do that.

Comment: @User1 - I agree that it would be handy to introduce an indicator of whether the poster is a native speaker or not, to help OPs find better answers. However, I find it perfectly okay to be guessing and making errors, this is part of the process of learning. I don't need advice on finding other venues for posting my answers. If you don't like any of my answers, feel free to downvote them and to criticize specific points, but do not feel free to give your valuable advice on someone's "going elsewhere". If you don't like non-natives posting answers here, well, try to change the rules of the site.

Comment: Being a native speaker doesn't automatically make everything people say about language right, or else we wouldn't have nearly as many wrong answers on ELL. And equally, being a non-native speaker doesn't automatically make everything people say about language wrong.  I personally believe CopperKettle's contributions to ELL are quite valuable and hope he continues to post :-)

Answer (score 2):

SUPPLEMENTAL to CopperKettle's answer
In the comments to this answer, Bart-leby asks whether *as they went along*  should be cast in the progressive, *as they **were going** along*.

*GO*, by itself, is what linguists call an 'activity' verb: it is *atelic*, having no 'endpoint' built in to its sense.

Consequently, in contexts like *as they went along*, it is inherently continuous; casting it in the progressive is superfluous.

Things get more complicated if an explicit goal is provided—for instance, if we speak of going *to London* or *toward London*. That goal may recategorize *GO* as an 'accomplishment' verb: one which is *telic*, with an endpoint built in to the context. For example:

- If you say *They went **to Walsingham***, the simple past *went* has a 'perfective'<sup>†</sup> sense: we understand that the journey was completed, "accomplished".
- In older English, and in literary registers, that recategorization is rolled back in contexts where an imperfective sense is clearly intended—for instance, with *as* in the Elizabethan ballad *As I went to Walsingham [I met a jolly palmer]*, which speaks of something that happened *during* the journey.
- But in Present-day English, *GO **to** X* remains recategorized in other contexts. We prefer you to cast *GO* in the progressive:

  > As I **was going** to Walsingham I met a jolly palmer.

Aspect recategorization is complicated, and varies not only with period and register but also with the particular verb—and even with the particular preposition which supplies the goal. For instance: *GO* + *toward* is inherently **imp**erfective, so use of the perfective simple past *went toward* implies recategorization as an 'inchoative':

> The next morning I went toward Walsingham *means I **started** a journey toward Walsingham*.

---

<sup>†</sup> Note that *perfective* has nothing to do with the construction we call the "perfect"—that name for the construction is an accident of history.

Answer (score 1):

As a native speaker of English,
it seems to me these two sentences mean the same thing:

> They were having to make everything up as they went along.
>
> They had to make everything up as they went along.

Not only that, I regard the second sentence as *better,* because
it expresses the same idea more clearly and directly.

Both sentences imply that the process of making things up was
a continuous process, since it occurred "as they went along."
In other words, *making everything up as they went along*
was the thing that the French Revolutionaries *had to* do.
Logically, I suppose you might say that was the thing they *were having to* do,
but I would never say that.

Finally, "as they went along" has a clear, idiomatic meaning that is
obscured if you change it to "as they were going along,"
so I would not do that.

Answer (score 0):

I am a native speaker and my answer is not a guess.

> When he talks of "enemies of the people", the analogies with Stalinist Russia and other 20th-century regimes are so glaring that you have to keep reminding yourself that the French Revolutionaries **were having to** make everything up as they went along, against a very different background from that of the 20th-century tyrannies.

The verb in question is not "have" but "have to." And yes this verb works very much like "must." For example, instead of saying

> I **must** admit that I have never come across this form.

you could say

> I **have to** admit that I have never come across this form.

The  difference between *must* and *have to* is that in the former, the obligation of the speaker is imposed, whereas in the latter, some other obligation is imposed. See [“I have to” vs. “I must”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/71001/i-have-to-vs-i-must).

And yes, "were having to" is a progressive form of "have to." Namely it is the past progressive. The present progressive is "am having to."

The use of the past progressive here (*were having to*) is not required by either (a) "as they went along," (b) anything else in the near context, including other uses of the progressive, such as "are so glaring" and "have to keep reminding yourself." And yes, you could write the sentence as:

> When he talks of "enemies of the people", the analogies with Stalinist Russia and other 20th-century regimes are so glaring that you have to keep reminding yourself that *the French Revolutionaries **had to** make everything up as they went along*, against a very different background from that of the 20th-century tyrannies.

However, by changing the aspect *you are changing the meaning (e.g., what is expressed by the aspect)*. In this case, the original is using the past progressive and your version uses the past simple. Either one is fine; again, nothing in the context requires that either aspect be used. It is the author alone here that prefers the progressive, much to the detriment of his prose.

> > P.S. And what about this swap of aspect:
>
> "Revolutionaries had to make everything up as they were going along".

Yes, that is acceptable. All that does is stretch out the activity of *they went along* (i.e., you have another example of the normal difference between the simple past and the progressive past).